# How to get the timestamp of sensors in .NET MAUI?

Tags: c#, android, .net, maui

```
For example, I want to monitor the accelerometer for changes and get the time when the change happens. The following code example is copied from the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/device/sensors?view=net-maui-7.0&tabs=android):
```

```
private void Accelerometer_ReadingChanged(object sender, AccelerometerChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // Update UI Label with accelerometer state`your text`
    AccelLabel.TextColor = Colors.Green;
    AccelLabel.Text = $"Accel: {e.Reading}";
}
```

```
`Reading` is the only property in `AccelerometerChangedEventArgs`, which is of type  `AccelerometerData`. And `AccelerometerData` also has only one property which is `Vector3`.So I don't know how to get the accurate time the accelerometer acquires the current data.
```

I've tried to use `DateTime.Now` in `Accelerometer_ReadingChanged` instead, just like:

```
private void Accelerometer_ReadingChanged(object sender, AccelerometerChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // Update UI Label with accelerometer state`your text`
    AccelLabel.TextColor = Colors.Green;
    AccelLabel.Text = $"Accel: {e.Reading}";
    Time=DateTime.Now;
}
```

But it seems to be kind of weird since it is not the real time when the data changes. There is a period of time between when the accelerometer actually gets the data and when the event responds. The timestamp on the accelerometer data is the real time. I need to get the exact time because of the algorithm I used.

Comment: It seems a bit weird you're trying to do that in the UI. Don't you have an application layer to manage the data?

Comment: @PMF It's just a code sample copied from the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/device/sensors?view=net-maui-7.0&tabs=android).

Comment: it doesn't appear that MAUI exposes the underlying timestamp data

Comment: @Jason Is it possible to write platform-specific codes to get the timestamp data?

Comment: I'm sure it is.  You can look at the implementation of the existing accelerometer classes to see how they are ingesting the native platform data and if there are timestamps available that you could add